# Swiper.js and UIWebView not accepted by Apple App Store

Tags: cordova, swiper.js

When I submit my Cordova app that using Swiper.js, I'm getting the following error.

TMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - App updates that use UIWebView will no longer be accepted as of December 2020. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).  After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App Store Connect.

Anyway to update Swiper to support WKWebView instead?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In xcode, simply find and replace UIWebView instances with WKWebView. Swiper seems to have references in comments only and a variable isUIWebView.